# Varying power output using RPI

Tags: remote

I'm planning to develop a circuit to control the RC car or a model train through GPIO. I'm not a electronic guy but a SW guy. So, I'm figuring out what components would be required to do this.

Basically the requirement is to vary the power source in order to control the speed of the train or car through software using RPI. Any heads up on this will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance. I tried to search the archives but failed to find the one that helped me. Sorry if this has been already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Vadiraj, I think you are after PWM (pulse width modulation). Also note the Pi can't provide much power output, so you need to drive it through a circuit that can give the appropriate power to your device.

[Here's a great tutorial from Adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/overview) on using PWM on the Pi.

Comment: I found another project which is close to what I want to do. Will explore from pi angle.

http://4micro.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/project-2-wiimote-arduino-rc-car-hours-of-fun/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I found this one very close to what I want to do. Hopefully I understand more on this electronic stuff before I start with the code.

http://4micro.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/project-2-wiimote-arduino-rc-car-hours-of-fun/